# Postfix incrementer overloading for nested enumerated types

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, enumerated-types

I am having difficulty figuring out how to overload the postfix increment operator for an nested enumerated type of class Card. Moreover, I am also having difficulty getting copy assignment to work for this class. I am getting the following errors "operator++ must take one or zero arguments." Then, when I attempt to provide assignment I get

```
no match for operator= in ((deck*)->this)->Deck::deckArr = operator new
```

---

```
class Card {
  public:
    enum Suit {
      SPADES,
      HEARTS,
      CLUBS,
      DIAMONDS
    };

    enum Spot {
      DEUCE,
      THREE,
      FOUR,
      FIVE,
      SIX,
      SEVEN,
      EIGHT,
      NINE,
      TEN,
      JACK,
      QUEEN,
      KING,
      ACE
   };

   Card();
   Card(Card&);
   Card(Suit&, Spot&);
   ~Card();

   Suit& operator++(Suit&,int);
   Spot& operator++(Spot&,int);
   Card& operator=(const Card&);

 private:
   Spot _spot;
   Suit _suit;
};

Card::Suit& Card::operator++(Card::Suit &s, int) {Card::Suit oldsuit = s;
                                            s = (Card::Suit)(s+1);
                                            return oldsuit;}
Card::Spot& Card::operator++(Card::Spot &sp, int){Card::Spot oldspot = sp;
                                            sp = (Card::Spot)(sp+1);
                                            return oldspot;}
Card& Card::operator=(const Card &c){_spot = c._spot; _suit = c._suit; return *this;}


#include "card.h"

class Deck {
 public:
    Deck();
    Deck(Deck&);
    ~Deck();

    void createDeck();
    void shuffleDeck(int);
 private:
    static const int DECK_SIZE = 52;
    Card deckArr[DECK_SIZE];
};

void Deck::createDeck(){
    int x = 0;
    for(Card::Suit s = Card::SPADES; s <= Card::HEARTS; s++){
        for(Card::Spot n = Card::DEUCE; n <= Card::ACE; n++, x++){
             deckArr[x] = new Card(s, n);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your `Card` constructor?

Comment: Also, the title seems to have nothing to do with the error message.

Comment: Why have you got "deckArr[x] = new Card(s, n);" near the end? Why *new*?

Comment: With regards to your implementation, you do _not_ want to return a reference to `oldsuit` or `oldspot`.

Comment: You're asking two separate questions. There's a good answer for the main question about operator overloading; the second one about `operator new` is because you're trying to assign to a `Card` *object* from a *pointer* to a dynamically allocated object. You want `deckArr[x] = Card(s,n);` to assign from a temporary object instead.

Comment: Even if I remove new, I'm still faced with the same error. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. If I am to construct a new Card with argument types Suit and Spot, what does that constructor need from me? All I get is ((Card*)this)->Card::Spot cannot be used as a function when I attempt to construct it. I know I'm probably missing something fundamental, but I'm completely lost.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that there is no way you can use a member
operator here.  A member operator *always* operates on the class
of which it is a member, and since you want it to operator on an
enum, and not on a class, it cannot be a member.

If you want ADL to find it, you'll have to make it a friend, in
order to declare (and possibly define it) inside the class:

```
friend Suit& operator++( Suit& s )
{
    s = static_cast<Suit>( s + 1 );
    return s;
}
friend Suit operator++( Suit& s, int )
{
    Suit result( s );
    s ++;
    return result;
}
```

and the same for Spot.

You'll also have to decide what to do when you iterate beyond
the end.  Casting `s + 1` back to the enum type is undefined
behavior, at least in the case of `Suit`.  A common convention
is to add an extra value for the end at the end; e.g. `END_Suit`
and `END_Spot`.  This allows simple and safe iteration:

```
for ( Suit s = SPADES; s != END_Suit; ++ s ) // ...
```

Otherwise, it gets tricky.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to overload `operator++`,

```
Card::Suit operator++(int){ } //would be suit++
```

and

```
Card::Suit& operator++() { } //would be ++suit
```

You must not pass anything to `operator++`, except a dummy parameter (usually `int`) and usually you don't pass back a `reference` in postfix.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846296/overloading-of-the-operator) for some information.

Comment: That's how to overload the operators as class members; but for enumerations we need to overload them as non-members.