# assigning a variable to pre-increment variable and post increment variable?

Tags: c++

What's the difference between the following two assignments?

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
int main(){
    int a=10,i=0;
    ++i = a //COMPILES WITHOUT ERROR
    i++ = a //GIVES AN ERROR LVALUE NEEDED
}
```

Why does the second assignment produce error?

Comment: `++i = a`, even though it compiles, is probably still undefined behaviour, at least prior to C++11.

Answer (score 4):

`++i` returns the new value of `i` after the incrementation. That value is an **lvalue**, called `i` in this case. Modifying `i` is certainly allowed.

But `i++` returns the old value of `i` before the incrementation. That value is an **rvalue**, i.e. an unnamed temporary value. Modifying an rvalue is not allowed in C++.

Comment: _"Modifying an rvalue is not allowed in C++"_ This is not a blanket rule.

Answer (score 0):

Pre-increment operation returns its argument (`i`) already incremented by one. The returned thing is *a variable* and you can assign to it.

Post-increment returns an old value of `i` - an *rvalue*, that cannot be assigned to.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3846296/4354477) for implementation of `operator++` in C++.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I mean, it's garbage for the programmer as this value is not needed any more

Comment: In 99% of cases that is not true, otherwise the construct would not exist. Usually when people say "garbage" they mean "arbitrary/unspecified value", which certainly doesn't describe this.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, to tell the truth, it wasn't too easy for me to choose the appropriate word in this particular case, so my choice may be wrong, I'll try to fix it now.