# Why use int as an argument for post-increment operator overload?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

As I know here is the way to overload the post-increment operator:

```
const MyClass& MyClass::operator++(int);
```

Why does it have int as an argument?

Comment: From [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4421719/499359) *The unary increment and decrement operators come in both prefix and postfix flavor. To tell one from the other, the postfix variants take an additional **dummy int argument***.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does the postfix increment operator take a dummy parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574831/why-does-the-postfix-increment-operator-take-a-dummy-parameter)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[D&E](http://www.stroustrup.com/dne.html), §11.5.3:

> I conisdered the obvious solution, adding the keywords `prefix` and `postfix` to C++ [ ... ]
> However I received the usual howl of outrage from people who dislike new keywords. Several alternatives that did not involve new keywords were suggested. For example:

> ```
> class Ptr_to_X {
>     X ++operator(); // prefix ++
>     X operator++(); // postfix ++
> };
> ```
>
> or

> ```
> class Ptr_to_X {
>     X& operator++(); // postfix because it 
>                      // returns a reference
>     X operator++();  // prefix because it
>                      // doesn't return a reference
> };
> ```

> I considered the former too cute and the latter too subtle. Finally I settled on:

> ```
> class Ptr_to_X {
>     X operator++();     // prefix: no argument
>     X operator++(int);  // postfix: because of the argument
> };
> ```

> This may be too cute and too subtle, but it works, requires no new syntax, and has a logic to the madness. Other unary operators are prefix and take no arguments when defined as member functions. The "odd" and unused dummy `int` argument is used to indicate the odd postfix operators. In other words, in the postfix case, `++` comes between the first (real) operand and the second (dummy) argument and is thus postfix.
> These explanations are needed because the mechanism is unique, and therefore a bit of a wart. Given a choice I would probably have introduced the `prefix` and `postfix` keywords, but that didn't appear feasible at the time.

Comment: thank you, I'm quit confuse. How to call a function without passing parameters, but the same functions, signature has parameters.

Comment: @NayanaAdassuriya: Simple: write `x++`, and that's the function that gets called. If you insist on calling it as `x.operator++`, then I believe you have to pass a parameter (which will be ignored): `x.operator++(1);`

Answer (score 3):

This is to distinguish between prefix increment and postfix increment operators.

For completeness, this is set out in §13.5.7 in both the C++03 and the C++11 standards.

Comment: @NayanaAdassuriya I believe it is just a convention.

Comment: Thanks juanchopanza:is this mentions in C++ standers?

Comment: @NayanaAdassuriya, *The user-deﬁned function called operator++ implements the preﬁx and postﬁx ++ operator. If this function is
a member function with no parameters, or a non-member function with one parameter of class or enumeration
type, it deﬁnes the preﬁx increment operator ++ for objects of that type. If the function is a member function
with one parameter (which shall be of type int) or a non-member function with two parameters (the second
of which shall be of type int), it deﬁnes the postﬁx increment operator ++ for objects of that type.* It says right after that the argument is 0.

Comment: @NayanaAdassuriya see §13.5.7.

Comment: @chris : thank you. So you are call call a function without parameter. but it's signature have a parameter. How come this?

Comment: @NayanaAdassuriya if you call the operator explicitly, you would have to pass a dummy `int` argument. I must say, I find this dummy parameter convention rather "hacky".

Comment: Note: in N4687, it is in 16.5.7