# Mneumonic for remembering which overload is predecrement/postdecrement

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I know that `operator++(int)` is the post-increment operator.  I know this because I just [looked it up](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec), like I have to every single time I overload the increment or decrement operator... sometimes multiple times in one coding session.

Is there any rationale or mneumonic which is used to explain why post-increment gets the dummy argument?

Answer (score 1):

I use the fact that there is a parameter after the operator to remember it is the operator for when `++` is after the variable.

Comment: I never thought of it that way; that's a lot more clever than mine. Have an upvote!

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a subjective question, but the way I choose to remember this is that the pre-increment always return a reference (since it modifies itself), whereas the post-increment requires a copy.

With that in mind, you just need to remember that the returns a reference doesn't take the dummy parameter.

```cpp
foo& foo::operator++();   // pre-increment
foo foo::operator++(int); // post-increment
```

---

As for rationale for the dummy parameter, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3576289/1678770)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using pre-increment things are easy, the variable gets incremented and you can use the value of the variable itself for further calculation.
If you are using post-increment things are not as easy, you need to keep track of the value before increment or you need to do the increment after you are done with the calculation.

The more complex thing gets the "additional" parameter.